# Confused with finding C in economic integral

Tags: integration

Question:

**An automobile company is ready to introduce a new line of cars. They project that the sales will increase by:
$P'(t)=10-10e^{-0.1t}, 0\leq t\leq 24$
in t months after the campaign has started.
(A) - What will be the total sales S(t) t months after the beginning of the campaign if we assume no sales at the beginning of the campaign?**

So I integrate the marginal function and get:

$10t-100e^{-0.1t}+C$ but my book gets the same answer except that C is +100. How does my calculus text book author arrive at this conclusion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** How many cars are sold at time $t=0$ months? Use that condition (also known as initial condition) in your expression for $P(t)$ and solve for $C$.

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick. I will accept your answer in 9 minutes when it opens up.